# how to launch safari even when the url is not valid

Tags: ios, safari, launch

I know how to launch safari using the:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

But, this method returns false when the url is not valid, and nothing happens. So, I'd like to launch safari even when the url is invalid. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

NO it is not possible to open URL *(which is invalid)* with safari or any other bowser in `iOS` or another `OS`, So it's better to make valid URL rather then fighting with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code check, if the URL is valid or not.

```
NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:candidate];
if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host) 
{
      //Open that URL using openURL method...
}
else
{
     //Open any valid hardcoded URL using openURL method
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the openURL already does it. I'd like to open the link independently it's valid or not...

Comment: Invalid link get open (provided its a valid URL). but invalid URL can not get opened...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? No.

Long answer? Technically No. But there is a workaround. If you use a redirection service/url shortener, you can hide your invalid url. For example, try this url: http://goo.gl/zRci0B
Safari will be able to open the link but it wont go anywhere. So what ever url(valid/invalid) you want to open, always wrap it with a redirection service.

Comment: Workarounds, workarounds everywhere! haha
Thank you for the help, I'll check this "alternative"...